# pasar lista a fichero excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, lista, diccionarios

yo quiero añadir una lista a un fichero .xslx
lo hago asi pongo la lista y como lo hecho pero me da
un error de columna de pais que no se resolver ..

```
lista = [{"pais": "USA", "moro": 46, "mplata": 12,"mbronce":5},
         {"pais": "China", "moro": 38, "mplata": "20","mbronce":7},
         {"pais": "uk", "moro": 29, "mplata": 7,"mbronce":7},
         {"pais": "russia", "moro": 22, "mplata": 10,"mbronce":9},
         {"pais": "South Korea", "moro": 13, "mplata": 3,"mbronce":2},
         {"pais": "Germany", "moro": 11, "mplata": 7,"mbronce":4}]     
                         
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
hoja = wb.active
                        
# Crea la fila del encabezado con los títulos
for producto in lista:
    # producto es una tupla con los valores de un producto 
    hoja.append(producto)

# Guardar cambios
wb.save("02_Excel_data.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes instalado `pandas` y `openpyxl` te recomiendo hacerlo directamente usando pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

# Conviertes la lista de diccionarios en un dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lista)

# Guardas el dataframe en formato de excel
df.to_excel('02_Excel_data.xlsx', index=None)
```

Comment: No hay necesidad de usar el método `from_dict` pues pandas acepta los diccionarios para la creación de un DataFrame por lo que `pd.DataFrame(lista)` basta

Comment: tengo que hacerlo con openpyxl sin usar panda

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que lo que le estas pasando a `hoja.append()` es un diccionario (producto del `for`) y lo que necesitas es pasar una tupla de los valores, para eso deberemos de convertirlos a tal.

```py
for producto in lista:
    prd = list(producto.values())
    hoja.append(prd)
```

Los diccionarios tienen el método `values` que nos devuelve un `dict_values` con los   valores de las claves del diccionario, pero `openpyxl` no necesita un `dict_values`, necesita una lista, por eso usamos la clase `list` para transformarlo a una lista. Sin embargo con lo que hemos hecho simplemente se nos agrega las filas pero no los encabezados (nombre de las columnas) y lo que se me ocurrió fue hacer un `hoja.append(list(lista[0].keys()))` antes del `for`, quedando el código así

```py
lista = [{"pais": "USA", "moro": 46, "mplata": 12,"mbronce":5},
         {"pais": "China", "moro": 38, "mplata": "20","mbronce":7},
         {"pais": "uk", "moro": 29, "mplata": 7,"mbronce":7},
         {"pais": "russia", "moro": 22, "mplata": 10,"mbronce":9},
         {"pais": "South Korea", "moro": 13, "mplata": 3,"mbronce":2},
         {"pais": "Germany", "moro": 11, "mplata": 7,"mbronce":4}]     
                         
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
hoja = wb.active
                        
hoja.append(list(lista[0].keys()))

for producto in lista:
    prd = list(producto.values())
    hoja.append(prd)
#el for lo puedes reemplazar por 
# hoja = [list(producto.values()) for producto in lista]

wb.save("02_Excel_data.xlsx")
```

Si eres un poco más avanzado en python puedes usar una comprensión de lista para reemplazar el ciclo `for`.

```py
hoja = [list(producto.values()) for producto in lista]
```

No soy experto en openpyxl por lo que tal vez haya una solución más simplificada, pero si te recomiendo usar `pandas`.

Comment: muchas gracias funciona bien , gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: de nada ^_^. Recuerda que puedes marcar como aceptada la respuesta